# Looking for Tim Omernick's Fireworks iPhone app

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, eaglview

Does anyone have the Fireworks app that Tim Omernick (of ngmoco) posted here:
gamemakers.ngmoco.com/post/111712416/stanford-university-and-apple-were-kind-enough-to

He originally provided a download link to the source code, but the download link is down and just says "Account Suspended".

I am currently working on my own OpenGL ES game for the iPhone and I would really love to look at the optimizations that he used in his app!  Would anyone be able to provide a working download link??

Answer (score 5):

You can have a look at this [presentation](http://e-learning.cs.usm.my/apple/iPhone-Dev-Stanford/OpenGL.pdf) Tim made for the Stanford students.

Apple has, in their documentation, some recommendations one can [follow](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html)

I also found the source code on my old machine. Looked at his copyright and it looks ok to republish so I have posted it on [`github`](http://github.com/epatel/Fireworks-by-Tim)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I have seen the presentation already.  I downloaded the video of it from iTunes U.

What I am interested in is looking at the source so I can really see the nitty-gritty details of what he did, how he structured his interleaved arrays, etc.

Comment: @spenceGL Quote from the docs "Best Practices on the PowerVR MBX - For best performance, you should interleave the standard vertex attributes in the following order: Position, Normal, Color, TexCoord0, TexCoord1, PointSize, Weight, MatrixIndex."

Comment: Thank you so much epatel!  I cannot even describe how grateful I am.  Thanks for coming through for me, and responding so fast!

Answer (score 2):

http://github.com/epatel/Fireworks-by-Tim

Thanks Tim from Alkmaar Holland